# Fixed action bar, taking footer into account

Tags: html, css, asp.net, webforms

I've been trying to get an 'action bar' to appear on my web application using position fixed. This action bar will contain various buttons relevant to the active form, and should always be visible at the bottom of the users view making its primary functions easy to access.

Using position fixed, I've managed to get it working to a certain extent but it interferes with my page footer which is always stuck at the bottom. Is there a way to make the action bar sit on top of the footer instead of overlapping, without using JavaScript or JQuery to determine when to push the bar up.

Please refer to the snippet provided:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.example-header {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  
}

.example-inner-body {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

.example-inner-body span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.action-bar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

footer {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
  <title>Page Title</title> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <div class="example-header">Header</div>
    <div class="example-inner-body">iBody
    <span> Don't go below me, but feel free to go up!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="action-bar">Action Bar</div>
    <footer>Footer - Do not cover me! </footer>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Edit:

Using a margin isn't sufficient, as when scrolling a white gap is then present underneath (where the footer would of been).

Comment: Since you know the footer height, go ahead with `.action-bar { bottom: 40px;}`

Comment: That would leave a white gap underneath when scrolling up which I forgot to mention, sorry!

Comment: In that case you can set `.action-bar {
  position: sticky; }`, but it is not widely supported https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: Thanks, I've never used that before. I'll keep that in mind, I may have to resort to JQuery, and keep it at the bottom if JavaScript is disabled but I'd prefer not too.

Comment: I have used this polyfill at some point -> https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill, which is quite good. It will not do anything if the browser has native support for `position: sticky`

Comment: Hi, thanks for all your help. Polyfill looks interesting, but I think for the time being I'm simply going to set the action bar to position relative, and then set it to sticky so that if browser doesn't support it then it will stay at the bottom. Good call on sticky!

Comment: No probs, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the suggestion by **Morpheus** in the questions comments, I'm going to use position sticky. As the user has stated, it isn't well supported so what I've done is first set the action bar to relative, and then to sticky so there is always a fallback.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.example-header {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  
}

.example-inner-body {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

.example-inner-body span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.action-bar {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  
}

footer {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
  <title>Page Title</title> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <div class="example-header">Header</div>
    <div class="example-inner-body">iBody
    <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="action-bar">Action Bar</div>
    <footer>Footer - Do not cover me! </footer>
  </body> 
</html>
```