# Hiding content behind action bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to get content to hide behind actionbar when scrolling. 
 I have this example pen:
https://codepen.io/Wocha/pen/ExKVNRW

HTML:

```
  <div class="app-content">
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="content">
      Some main content
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      Footer content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: #F2F3F5;
}

.app-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.main-content {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

.content {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 16px;
  min-height: 82vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.footer {
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

What i would like is for content to hide behind footer / actionbar when scrolling so that there would always be a small line of background gray visible between footer and content.

I could do it by setting content height and overflow: auto, but that would create extra scrollbar to content div and i want it to work when scrolling main window.

This post is very close to what i would like to happen, but there Action Bar just scrolls over content, same as in my pen example. 
[Fixed action bar, taking footer into account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910372/fixed-action-bar-taking-footer-into-account)

Comment: So you want a small border of gray between the main content and the footer? Or do you want the main content to be invisible below the footer? Am I getting this right?

Comment: Action bar is stickied to the bottom. When scrolling i want main content to not be visible behind action bar. Line of gray (background) would be small amount of padding added to action bar.

Comment: You could make a div that's the color of your background and put it below the footer. Then set its position also fixxed and z-index to 1

Comment: Tried this solution, but looked a little wierd because main content is inside segment with bottom border format. Currently gave up and left it like it is in example.

Answer (score 0):

change the z index of the action bar to 1

```
z-index: 1;
```

Comment: Setting z-index changes nothing in the behaviour. When i scroll content, it is still visible behind action bar.